# Is there any difference between docker run '--security-opt seccomp=unconfined' and '--privileged' for a container without exposed services?

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any difference between:

```
docker run --security-opt seccomp=unconfined
```

and

```
docker run --privileged
```

? I need to run a `chromedriver/chromium` instance in `docker`, and if I don't do this, I have this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Or is there a better way?